# Compute $\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x(x+(\ln x)^2)}$

Tags: calculus

My friend asked me how to integrate the following:
$$\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x(x+(\ln x)^2)}$$

How am I going to solve this?Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This strongly suggests the substitution $u = \ln x$.

Comment: @T.Bongers The resulting integral is still fairly challenging IMO, and makes me wonder if the problem should actually read $\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x(1+(\ln x)^2)}$.

Comment: @DavidH Perhaps; it doesn't look like there's a closed form for this integral.

Comment: Maple doesn't give an answer, except when asked to do it numerically; then it gives 0.5657522781. (When I ask for 50 digits, I get 0.56575227809794093284778647981402016035012640346360).

Comment: Have you checked, Philip, whether @David is right?

Answer (score -2):

Assume $u=\ln x$, then
\begin{align}
I:=\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x(x+(\ln x)^2)}
=\int_0^1 \frac{e^u du}{e^u(e^u+u^2)}
&=\int_0^1 \frac{ du}{e^u+u^2}
\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-u} du}{1+u^2e^{-u}}
\end{align}
Using geometric series $$\frac{1}{1+u^2e^{-u}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^nu^{2n} e^{-nu} }$$ term by term integration, we have
\begin{align}
I=\sum(-1)^n (\int_0^1 {  u^{2n} e^{-(n+1)u}du}=J_n)
\end{align}
Integrating by parts we get (from tables) $$J_n=-e^{-(n+1) u}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-k)!}(n+1)^{-(k+1)}u^{2n-k}$$

Comment: The solution is updated

Comment: If $J_n$ stands for an integral, then it should not depend on $u$. Is your $J_n$ a function of $u$ and you mean $J_n(1) - J_n(0)$ in your expression of $I$?

Comment: Yes exactly, l post from a smart phone so it is difficult on me to print.